# How to check if Windows Modal Dialog is present using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a Windows Modal Dialog that appears at times for some tests and then other times it does not appear.

[image]

I know when it will possibly show up. I want to be able to grab the window handle of the modal dialog and send the enter key to dismiss it.

Is it possible to detect if a modal dialog is present using the Selenium web driver?

Comment: are you using webdriver?

Comment: @Jon: When Modal dialog Box appears, can you tell me where the cursor/mouse is ? If you Hit Enter does Modal Dialog Box closes?

Comment: I'm using the Selenium WebDriver, when the Modal Dialog Box appears an exception is thrown and the test is aborted. If I press the enter key then the Modal Dialog Closes.

Comment: Then I think @bcar's answer is the one you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a javascripty alert box then

```
IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
alert.Accept();
```

Should be sufficient to acknowledge.

Answer (score 0):

After we perform the action which opens Modal Dialog box, Try Using Robot class, Used Manual wait of 7 sec though its not good practice, you can change it as per your requirement. See if that works.

```
Robot robot = new Robot();

Thread.sleep(7000);

robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); 

robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```